# How to prevent Time out when Automate Excel via Visual C++?

Tags: excel, visual-c++, automation, timeout

I am using Visual C++ 2008 to automate Excel 2010, as below:

```
    CApplication ExcelApp;

    if (ExcelApp.CreateDispatch(_T("Excel.Application"), NULL))
    {
        CWorkbooks oWorkbooks;
        CWorkbook oWorkbook;

        //  Add a workbook
        oWorkbooks = ExcelApp.get_Workbooks();
        oWorkbook = oWorkbooks.Add(vOpt);

        //  Wait for user input
        //  ::Sleep(1000 * 60 * 15);

        oWorkbook.Activate();

        //  Save workbook           
        oWorkbook.SaveAs(COleVariant(strExcelFile), COleVariant((long)xlOpenXMLWorkbook), COleVariant(_T("")), COleVariant(_T("")),
                vFalse, vOpt, (long)xlNoChange, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt, vOpt);

        ExcelApp.Quit();
    }
```

During the automation process, I need to wait for user input and save it into the Excel workbook. If the wait time is long, for example, 15 minutes, then the upcoming SaveAs method will fail with error code 0x800a03ec, which is described at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/92ad0462-5bfe-4353-b9e2-d13e93e712c8/cannot-save-workbook-via-automation?forum=exceldev .

In my code comment, I use a Sleep function to simulate the 15 minute wait time which will cause the error.

In such a case, is there a way to keep the automation active to prevent the time out of the automation connnection?

To easily reproduce the error, I make the following two test projects in VS2008:

1. EADLL, which is a MFC DLL. It contains a TestExcel function that will automate Excel 2010 and invoke SaveAs to save Excel file as .xlsx file format. If let the sleep time to 15 mins, then an exception will occurs.
2. EAApp, which is a Dialog-based App to invoke the DLL.

I retest EADLL & EAApp on Windows 7 Ultimate(with SP1) 64bit version and confirm the error will occur when sleep 15 mins.

Both EADLL and EAApp are zipped and can be downloaded from:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6btgglnt9znadwp/EA.zip?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to call some simple method periodically?

Comment: THank you very much. The problem has been solved. The problem occurs because the Excel installed on local computer is not activated. After activating it, the problem is solved.

Comment: You should answer yourself to close the question;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the Excel installed on local computer is not activated. After activating it, the problem is solved.